# create session with recordset stored in array

Tags: php, arrays, session, recordset

How can I take a recordset, store it in an array and then make that array the value of a session?   Here is the code I came up with (with answers below integrated):

```
$colname_getAC = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['tech_id'])) {
  $colname_getAC = $_GET['tech_id'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_getAC = sprintf("SELECT area_code, tech_id FROM zip_zip WHERE tech_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_getAC, "int"));
$getAC = mysql_query($query_getAC, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getAC = mysql_fetch_assoc($getAC);
$totalRows_getAC = mysql_num_rows($getAC);
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['area_code']= array();
while ($row_getAC = mysql_fetch_assoc($getAC)) {
  $_SESSION['area_code'][] = $row_getAC['area_code'];
}
```

This just returns "array" though and not the area codes when I call the session.

On the session, I tried this also:

```
$_SESSION['area_code']= $results[];
```

But that just made the page stop dead in its tracks with a blank screen.

The reason for this is that I want to insert the values in this session on a different page.

Comment: _“This just returns "array" though and not the area codes when I call the session.”_ – then most likely your “calling of the session” is wrong. (You are aware that trying to output an array via echo will get you just that text exactly, right?)

Comment: I thought that made it get each value?

Comment: Well I want to insert it into the database on a different page.  Is that the same result as echoing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it stored as an array, you can see it here:

```
var_dump($_SESSION['area_code']);
```

I really dont understand, what exactly you want.

Also this is wrong `$_SESSION['area_code']= $results[];`

**EDITED:**
Change your code to:

```
$colname_getAC = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['tech_id'])) {
  $colname_getAC = $_GET['tech_id'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_getAC = sprintf("SELECT area_code, tech_id FROM zip_zip WHERE tech_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_getAC, "int"));
$getAC = mysql_query($query_getAC, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_getAC = mysql_num_rows($getAC);
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['area_code']= array();
while ($row_getAC = mysql_fetch_assoc($getAC)) {
  $_SESSION['area_code'][] = $row_getAC['area_code'];
}
```

Comment: This stopped my page from executing.  If I remove the bracket at the end, the array ends up being 0?

Comment: Yours is showing array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "757" }.  Not both area codes also.  I've updated my code to include the recordset.  Is something wrong on my end?

Comment: Yes, its wrong, I will paste here correct code. You are doing mysql_fetch_assoc before `while`... So i just removed that line. See my code.

Comment: That fixes it, for both of your answers. I appreciate the help! Since I had $row_getAC = mysql_fetch_assoc($getAC);, could I just have said $_SESSION['area_code'] = $row_getAC?

Comment: `$_SESSION['area_code'] = $row_getAC['area_code'];` this will store only last area_code, you will overwrite it in each loop in `while`. `$_SESSION['area_code'][] = $row_getAC['area_code'];` will add area_code to next key of an array.

Answer (score 1):

First - you must change your logic:

From this:

```
$results = array();
do {
  $results[] = $row_getAC['area_code'];
} while ($row_getAC = mysql_fetch_assoc($getAC));
$_SESSION['area_code']= $results;
```

to this:

```
$results = array();
while ($row_getAC = mysql_fetch_assoc($getAC))
{
   $results[] = $row_getAC['area_code'];
} 
$_SESSION['area_code']= $results;
```

I've just tested - PHP has no trouble storing arrays as session variables and they are available on other pages.

BTW - you used **session_start()** right?

**Update:**

- do{...}while always executes at least once as checks condition at the end
- while{...} exactly the opposite (checks condition before executing code inside code block

You must use the latter here since (for example) your SQL query may return empty result (no records) so you should not execute code within while block since there is no data to get.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand DO and WHILE correctly.  What is the difference in yours and mine?

Comment: do...while will execute atleast once, and also first execution will be false, because $row_getAC is empty in first loop.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my code, now it is only storing the last area code (out of two.)  The recordset is getting 614 and 757, but the array var_dump says, array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "757" }   Should I add my code for the recordset above?

Comment: So, let's say there might be music playing.  A do...while loop will say, "Clap once, and then see if music is playing and then clap or don't clap".   And just a while loop will say, "Check for music, then clap if music is playing."   Is that what you guys mean?

Comment: @SherewoodPro: I would rephrase it and say: while.. = check if there is a green light and if yes cross the street. Do..while = cross the street and later check what the light was.